# Oops! Something went wrong on location map at contact us page

Tags: magento-1.9, google-map

I am working on magento-1.9 version. When I am going to contact us page, I got the following error which is `Oops! Something went wrong`.

Please help me on this. Please let me know the requirements what I have to share here to get the solution.[image]

Based on user SH Patel's suggestion, i ran the URL with my API key. Then i got following screen. Please find the attachment.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google map JS use API for display map.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Check API key which you have used, Check API for host is match for your current host or not.

Comment: I mean check created API which you have used is specific for domain.

Comment: Can you give me site URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to setup the google map.

Step 1: Generate API key.

- Get an API key from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).
- Go to the Google API Console.
- Create or select a project.
- Click Continue to enable the API and any related services.
- On the Credentials page, get an API key (and set the API key
  restrictions).
  [image]

Step 2: Create configuration file to add the below Javascript file.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

**Configuration file**

To do this use the same script or link XML as normal but include src_type="url". As noted in the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```